Prevent inherited classes from having public constructor but push to have static factory function
I'm writing an abstract class, and many other classes will be inherited from it. Abstract class inherits from std::enable_shared_from_this class. On cppreference's example page the best way of working with this is removing public constructor:
class Best : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Best>
{
    struct Private{ explicit Private() = default; };
 
public:
    // Constructor is only usable by this class
    Best(Private) {}
 
    // Everyone else has to use this factory function
    // Hence all Best objects will be contained in shared_ptr
    static std::shared_ptr<Best> create()
    {
        return std::make_shared<Best>(Private());
    }
 
    std::shared_ptr<Best> getptr()
    {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
};

How do I enforce people, who will implement my abstract class, make constructor private but declare "static factory function".
Or maybe there's other way to hint people who will implement abstract class the correct way of doing it (except comments). There's no virtual static functions in c++ :(

A constructor cannot be static in c++. They're non-static member function by definition.

Why can't constructor be declared as static in c++? and What is a static constructor?

@user12002570 thank you, I have edited the question to be more accurate :)

You can't prevent people from shooting their foot off, especially not in C++. Document your class, put emphasis on the fact that it uses std::enable_shared_from_this and must be used within std::shared_ptr, maybe add an example of using factory method in derived class and trust in your colleagues.

you approach is flawed. Once a type appears in the signature of a public method, the type is publicly accessible. It is inconvenient but not impossible to use the type from outside (as in "not possible because it is private"). If you want to make it not possible you should make Best constructor private

on the other hand, you are already pushing users to use a static function. Also a derived class will have to construct a Best

@463035818_is_not_an_ai It's not my code, but the code from the cppreference example page, I've attached the link in my question :)

There are several issues with your current implementation:

Even if Private is in private section, we might still create one as long we don't use it name explicitly:

struct ToAny
{
    template <typename T>
    requires (std::is_default_constructible_v<T>)
    operator T() const { return T{}; } // Can construct `Private`
};


ignoring above ToAny, derived classes can use Best constructor in a limited way: they cannot spell Private, so the only solution is to inherit from Best constructor

class Derived : public Best
{
public:
    using Best::Best;
    // Derived(int) : Best(ToAny{}) {}
};

But creating Derived (unless ToAny is not possible)
You might change your factory method to permit to also construct derived:
template <std::derived_from<Best> T>
static std::shared_ptr<T> create()
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(Private());
}

There are still inconvenient, as derived classes cannot have extra parameters.
So fixing passkey idiom (Private): make it public with private constructor, and friend of Base;
And adjust factory to take extra parameter:
class Best : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Best>
{
public:
    class Key{
    private:
        friend Best;
        explicit Key() {}
    };

    // Constructor is only usable by this class
    Best(Key) {}
 
    // Everyone else has to use this factory function
    // Hence all Best objects will be contained in shared_ptr
    template <std::derived_from<Best> T, typename...Ts>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> create(Ts&&...args)
    {
        return std::make_shared<T>(Key(), std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
    // ..
};

Demo

Thanks for the answer, though it's not my code with private key, that's the correct answer the question. The problem here is Key - that makes code hard to read. Is it some way to make the code look prettier - but on the same time force all Derived not to have publicly available contructor - and the code to be as short as here https://godbolt.org/z/35n8P98Wo ?

I don't think there is an shorter alternative.

Thanks, I'm accepting your answer)
